# for loop execution in sql

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I know SQL can not do for loop, but I really need to make this query, but can not find a way. I have following code to be make in SQL.

```
List<MergerDic> allItems = (from row in dmVM
                            join t2 in mainDic on row.labelID equals t2.LabelId
                            where row.LanguageID == 20
                            orderby row.LabelValue
                            select new MergerDic
                                        {
                                            LabelId = row.labelID,
                                            LabelKey = t2.LabelKey,
                                            LanguageID = row.LanguageID,
                                            LabelValue = t2.LabelValue,
                                            LocalLabelValue = row.LabelValue
                                        }).ToList();

foreach (var item in allItems)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(item.LocalLabelValue))
    {
        item.LabelValue = allItems.FirstOrDefault(x => x.LabelValue == item.LabelValue &&
                !string.IsNullOrEmpty(x.LocalLabelValue)).LocalLabelValue;
        db.saveChanges();
    }
}
```

I have tried to make a temp table and than executing but didn't work. I get an error:

> String or binary data would be truncated.

The query I tried to write is just this much as below:

```
DROP TABLE #Temp

CREATE TABLE #Temp
(
    LabelId nvarchar(max),
    LabelValue nvarchar(max),
    LabelKey nvarchar(max),
    LanguageID int,
    LocalLabelValue nvarchar
)

INSERT INTO #Temp
    SELECT 
        dl.LabelID, dl.LabelValue, LabelKey, 20, dx.LabelValue 
    FROM
        DictionaryLocalized dx
    JOIN
        Dictionary dl ON dl.LabelID = dx.LabelID
    WHERE
        LanguageID = 20 
    ORDER BY
        dl.LabelValue

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN 
    --Do something with Id here
    PRINT 1
    FETCH NEXT FROM #Temp
END
```

Comment: Did you forget to add `(MAX)` after `LocalLabelValue` in your `CREATE TABLE` statement?

Comment: No its just doesn't needed

Comment: watch my C# code .... i need to make SQL Query to replace that piece

Comment: Why doing with cursor? you might do that without cursor in most of the scenarios... Also As BJones mentioned why LocalLabelValue is not assigned with NVARCHAR(...size...)

Comment: I just tried from my side .... i really have no idea how to do

Comment: So `dx.LabelValue` is nvarchar(1)?   Because that's what you're creating by not putting any length value in your create table statement.   If you try to insert more than 1 character in that column, you will get the truncation error you are getting.

Comment: Can you please post table structure for dvmVm and maindic

Comment: datatype are same at all columns ... nvarchar(max) ... let's just assume there is no error for column datatype ..... I need that C# function translated to SQL

Comment: Lookup TSQL cursor if you really want a loop.  Here is an example - https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1599/sql-server-cursor-example/.  From my experience any loop can be accomplished with a sql statement that usually runs faster, but its up to you.  Cursor will not solve your truncation issue.  Maybe post the schema of your tables?

Comment: Schema is same as the temptable's schema

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that db.saveChanges() and the INSERT statement in the SQL you have written indicates that you are trying to persist data to the database. If that is the case why do you have to do it row by row with a loop? Would a MERGE statement work for you if you have to INSERT or UPDATE depending on the situation?

Comment: yes but there is a if condition in C# code ... you can see

Comment: What you're checking with the IF in C#, you can condition out with a WHERE clause.

Answer (score 0):

Finally i created it on my own ....

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION
  BEGIN
    DECLARE @cntVar int = 0
    DECLARE @cntVarMax int = 0

    CREATE TABLE #Temp (
      REV_SEQ int IDENTITY (1, 1) PRIMARY KEY,
      LabelId nvarchar(max),
      LabelValue nvarchar(max),
      LabelKey nvarchar(max),
      LanguageID int,
      LocalLabelValue nvarchar(max)
    )

    INSERT INTO #Temp (LabelId, LabelValue, LabelKey, LanguageID, LocalLabelValue)
      SELECT
        row.LabelID AS LabelId,
        [t2].LabelValue AS LabelValue,
        t2.LabelKey AS LabelKey,
        20 AS LanguageID,
        row.LabelValue AS LocalLabelValue
      FROM dbo.DictionaryLocalized row
      JOIN dbo.Dictionary t2
        ON row.LabelID = t2.LabelID
      WHERE [row].LanguageID = 20
      AND (row.LabelValue = ''
      OR [row].LabelValue IS NULL)
      ORDER BY [t2].LabelValue


    SELECT
      @cntVarMax = COUNT(*)
    FROM #Temp

    WHILE @cntVar <= @cntVarMax
    BEGIN
      PRINT @cntVar
      --DECLARE @LabelData nvarchar(max)
      DECLARE @LabelID nvarchar(max)
      DECLARE @LabelVal nvarchar(max)

    --SELECT @LabelData = t.LocalLabelValue
    --FROM #Temp t WHERE t.REV_SEQ = @cntVar
    --IF  @LabelData = '' OR @LabelData IS NULL
    BEGIN
      SELECT
        @LabelVal = t.LabelValue
      FROM #Temp t
      WHERE t.REV_SEQ = @cntVar
      SELECT
        @LabelID = t.LabelKey
      FROM #Temp t
      WHERE t.REV_SEQ = @cntVar

      DECLARE @cnt1 int = 0

      SELECT
        @cnt1 = COUNT(dx.LabelValue)
      FROM DictionaryLocalized dx
      JOIN dbo.Dictionary t2
        ON dx.LabelID = t2.LabelID
      WHERE dx.LanguageID = 20
      AND t2.LabelValue = @LabelVal
      AND dx.LabelValue != ''
      AND dx.LabelValue IS NOT NULL

      IF @cnt1 > 0
      BEGIN
        UPDATE      dbo.DictionaryLocalized SET  dbo.DictionaryLocalized.LabelValue = 
        (SELECT TOP 1
          dx.LabelValue AS newvalue
        FROM DictionaryLocalized dx
        JOIN dbo.Dictionary t2
          ON dx.LabelID = t2.LabelID
        WHERE dx.LanguageID = 20
        AND t2.LabelValue = @LabelVal
        AND dx.LabelValue != ''
        AND dx.LabelValue IS NOT NULL)
        --SELECT ----------- remove this to updatd
          --dll.LabelID,
          --dll.LabelValue AS OldVal
        FROM DictionaryLocalized dll
        JOIN dbo.Dictionary t2
          ON dll.LabelID = t2.LabelID
        WHERE dll.LanguageID = 20
        AND t2.LabelValue = @LabelVal
        AND (dll.LabelValue = ''
        OR dll.LabelValue IS NULL)
      END
    END
      SELECT
        @cntVar = @cntVar + 1
    END

    DROP TABLE #Temp
  END
  ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
```

Thanks every one for support and help. and showing interest.